# Which function has this Taylor expansion around infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

The Taylor expansion of an unknown function is obtained as
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{4x^3} + \frac{9}{32x^5} + \frac{675}{512x^7} + \frac{55125}{4096x^9} + \frac{31255875}{131072x^{11}} + \frac{6807529575}{1048576 x^{13}} + \frac{4218399159975}{16777216 x^{15}} + \cdots ,
$$
which can be presented in the following form:
$$
f(x) =
\frac{1}{2^2 x^3}+
\frac{3^2}{2^5 x^5} + \frac{3^3 5^2}{2^9 x^7} + \frac{3^25^37^2}{2^{12} x^9} + \frac{3^65^37^3}{2^{17} x^{11}} + \frac{3^85^27^3 11^2}{2^{20} x^{13}} + \frac{3^7 5^27^3 11^3 13^2}{2^{24} x^{15}} + \cdots
$$

Expressing the latter infinite sum as a series with a general term is not obvious to me. It would be great if someone here could help or provide some useful hints to tackle this problem.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(k+1/2)^2\Gamma(k-1/2)}{\pi^{3/2}\Gamma(k)x^{2k+1}}$

Comment: By the [Watson lemma](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3.ii), a function with this asymptotic expansion can be represented as the Laplace transform of another function. Here, for example, $$ f(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^c \left[8E\left( \frac{t}{2}\right)-(4-t^2) K\left( \frac{t}{2} \right)\right]\frac{e^{-xt}}{(4-t^2)^2}\,dt$$
where $E$ and $K$ are the complete elliptic integrals and $0<c<2$. But this may not be very useful.